# Valgrind - understanding output for conditional jump

Tags: c, memory-management, shared-libraries, valgrind

I've been testing a C shared library for memory leaks. I got the output below, and I'd like to make sure my understanding of the output is correct.

I'm fairly well-acquainted with valgrind, but I'm used to the output having just one line below the "heap allocation" section, so I'd like to make sure I get this right. I tried to find more info in the valgrind manuals and here and other forums, but couldn't find anything.

Anyway, I ran with these parameters:
valgrind --leak-check=full --log-fd=1 --keep-debuginfo=yes --track-origins=yes

And got this output:

```
==28303== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28303==    at 0x82C80C0: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x830AA05: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x8301896: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0xB4E7E9A: func1 (in /opt/MyDir/MyExit.so_r)
==28303==    by 0xB4E9FFD: func2 (in /opt/MyDir/MyExit.so_r)
==28303==    by 0xB4EC62E: func3 (in /opt/MyDir/MyExit.so_r)
==28303==    by 0xB4ECB7C: func4 (in /opt/MyDir/MyExit.so_r)
==28303==    by 0x83AD1B7: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x831DA90: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x8301A1C: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x838DBCA: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x606E8A: ??? (in /opt/mqm/bin/dmpmqmsg)
==28303==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==28303==    at 0x6C29F73: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==28303==    by 0x8200401: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x848331B: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x839DC40: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x83167C4: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x83197D1: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x830092D: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x83833B4: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x838EE0C: ??? (in /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so)
==28303==    by 0x60316B: ??? (in /opt/mqm/bin/dmpmqmsg)
==28303==    by 0x7680554: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
```

(changed func names for security reasons)

Here's my understanding:

1. Memory was first allocated in "**libc-2.17.so**" (or was it in "**dmpmqmsg**"?), and was not initialized.
2. After that, the call sequence was as follows:
   libc-2.17.so >> dmpmqmsg >> libmqe_r.so >> MyExit.so_r (func4) >> ... >> MyExit.so_r (func1) >> libmqe_r.so
3. Finally the "conditional jump" which valgrind notified about was in **libmqe_r.so** at 0x82C80C0, probably an if(pmem != NULL) somewhere in this library

Is this the right interpretation?

In case it's relevant - I'm running on RedHat linux. My code is an MQ Exit which I compiled as a shared library.

Answer (score 0):

First, looking at the "heap allocation" callstack. At the top is `malloc` (which has been intercepted by memcheck). Then you have a series of 8 calls in `libmqe_r.so`, all without debug info. Then there's the call from the guest executable, `dmpmqmsg`. The last line in the callstack, in libc, is the startup function that calls `main`.

Next, the actual error. Without debug info, it will be difficult to be certain. It looks like your `func1` is calling a chain of 3 functions in `libmqe_r.so`, and passing in some uninitialized heap memory. It's also possible that your code is innocent and the topmost function is accessing some uninitialized static or global object.

I have almost no experience with MQ. There may be a package related to MQ that contains debugging symbols. Installing that would probably help.